# NextJS 13: Adding AdSense to the page - Ads seem to be invisible

Tags: reactjs, next.js, adsense

My goal is to add Google AdSense to a simple NextJS website. I followed the instructions by adding the script tag to the head, the  container to the specific pages during pageload I am pushing the ads to the container.

I see that the dom is getting injected with components and the page height will change a bit. So obviously something is happening, but I can't seem to find why I don't see any ads showing up?

Link to the preview: https://quote-van-de-dag.vercel.app/ (turn off adblocker)

PageLayout.tsx

```
  const pathName = usePathname();
  useEffect(() => {
    var ads = document.getElementsByClassName('adsbygoogle').length;
    for (var i = 0; i < ads; i++) {
      try {
        (window.adsbygoogle = window.adsbygoogle || []).push({});
      } catch (e) {}
    }
  }, [pathName]);
```

IndexPage.tsx

```
      <GoogleAdSenseContainer
          client="ca-pub-1265579553508424"
          slot="1768224699"
          responsive={true}
        />
```

GoogleAdSenseContainer.tsx

```
   <div
      style={{ overflow: 'hidden' }}
      key={adUnitKey}
    >
      <ins
        className="adsbygoogle"
        style={{ display: 'block' }}
        data-ad-client={client}
        data-ad-slot={slot}
        data-ad-format={responsive && 'auto'}
        data-full-width-responsive={responsive}
      ></ins>
    </div>
```

Comment: Your code looks fine. Make sure your AdSense is configured properly and set up to work with your serving domain. It may take a few days for the ads to show.

Answer (score 2):

The script should be loaded with `beforeInteractive` strategy.

```
import Script from 'next/script';

export default function(){
  return (<>
   <Script 
    id="adsbygoogle-init" 
    strategy="beforeInteractive" 
    crossOrigin="anonymous"
   src="https://pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/adsbygoogle.js?client=ca-pub-xxxx"></Script>
  <ins className="adsbygoogle"
    style={{ display: 'block' }}
    data-ad-client="ca-pub-xxx"
    data-ad-slot="xxx"
    data-ad-format="auto"
    data-full-width-responsive="true"
  />
  </>);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this package named `nextjs13_google_adsense` via `npm install nextjs13_google_adsense` or `yarn add nextjs13_google_adsense`.

after installing the package insert your google adsense ad unit code like this

```js
import GoogleAdUnit from 'nextjs13_google_adsense'

export default function MyPage() {
  return <>
  <div>Test Title</div>
  <GoogleAdUnit>
    <ins
          className="adsbygoogle"
          style={{ display: 'block', width: '100%' }}
          data-ad-client="ca-pub-1234567890"
          data-ad-slot="123456"
          data-ad-format="auto"
          data-full-width-responsive="true"
        ></ins>
  </GoogleAdUnit>
  <div>Test Content
  <>;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Make sure you didn't forget to add the main script to the _document.js (you have to convert it to tsx in your case, that's my example):

```
import { Html, Head, Main, NextScript } from 'next/document'

export default function Document() {
  return (
    <Html lang="en">
      <Head>
        <script async src="https://pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/adsbygoogle.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
      </Head>
      <body>
        <Main />
        <NextScript />
      </body>
    </Html>
  )
}
```

Btw, just tried to use native Script from next/stript, it didn't work, so had to revert to the regular  block.